# Why the if statement is ignored if input is meeting the required conditions?

Tags: java, string

I was generating a code which takes AM/PM format from the user and gives the output in 24-hour format. The program works fine for all inputs except when the input range of time is between "12:00:00 AM" to "12:00:00 PM"(Exclusive).

```
    String[] time = s.split(":");
    int hours = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time[1]);
    if(s.endsWith("AM")){
        time[2] = time[2].replace("AM","");
    }
    if(s.endsWith("PM")){
        time[2] = time[2].replace("PM","");
        if(hours != 12)hours+=12;
    }
    int seconds = Integer.parseInt(time[2]);

    String hh,mm,ss;
    if(hours < 10 && s.endsWith("AM")){
        hh = "0"+Integer.toString(hours);
    }
    if(hours == 12 && s.endsWith("AM")){
        hh = "00";
    }else{
        hh = Integer.toString(hours);
    }
```

Whenever I give input like 6:05:30 AM, hh returns the string "6" but the same time in PM format returns "06".

Comment: Unless you insist on reinventing the wheel, consider using the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: This line is interesting `if(hours == 12)hours = 12;` :)

Comment: It will not pass `int seconds = Integer.parseInt(time[2]);` if you used input like `6:05:30 AM` as the space after the seconds value will throw an exception....

Comment: I would use `split("[: ]+")` thus making `AM`/`PM` into `time[3]`...

Comment: Also which `AM`/`PM` system are you using?

Comment: Could you give us some example inputs and outputs? I don't see what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you omitted a `else` statement from the last block of `if` statements:

```
if(hours < 10 && s.endsWith("AM")){
    hh = "0"+Integer.toString(hours);
}
else // This one
if(hours == 12 && s.endsWith("AM")){
    hh = "00";
}else{
    hh = Integer.toString(hours);
}
```

Comment: @VaibhavPratihar Without that `else`, the `hh = Integer.toString(hours);` would execute even if `hours < 10 && s.endsWith("AM")` was true (causing it to overwrite). It connects the first conditional to the rest of the chain as it seems it should be.